# Generate data frame based on confsuion matrix

Tags: r

I have a confusion matrix like

```
    TP  TN  FP  FN
A   225 100 175 100
```

And i need to generate a dataframe with 2 features which exactly mock this confusion matrix. The data frame contains one feature called **play**, and the predictor is **sunnyDay**

It is easy to make the play feature with

```
playRecords <- sample( c(T,F), 500, replace=TRUE, prob=c( 0.5, 0.5) )

data.frame(play=playRecords,sunnyDay="")
```

But i have no idea, **how i can add observations of** **sunnyDay** in a way to make the exact confusion matrix?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it right, but isn't that dependent on your prediction model? So, by the confusion matrix you know how many positive predictions should be right, wrong .... but to create values for **play** you would need to know how the model *f(play) = sunnyDay* would work, right?

Comment: yes, but i considered `f(sunnyDay )=sunnyDay ` and **f** is the predictor

Comment: well then you create a dataframe with 2 columns *predicted* and *read*. You enter 225 rows where both are "sunnyDay", 100 rows where both are "noSunnyDay"... and so on